# Can't give permission to my Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions

I try to add a simple function to my Google Sheet to empty the data on a specific range.
But before i can run it i recieve a message that i need to autorize the script. In the next screen i can select my account. But then i only have a screen that says that the app is blocked. There is no option to accept it.
How can i run my script?

```
function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('My Menu')
      .addItem('Delete', 'delrange')
      .addToUi();
}
function delrange() {
SpreadsheetApp.app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:A10").clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the ".app" so that you end up with:

```
SpreadsheetApp
  .getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getActiveSheet()
  .getRange("A1:A10")
  .clearContent();
```